# How to make a script which uses $0 work when it's on $PATH?

Tags: bash, path

I have a script (~/.../gremlin) which I created a soft link for:

```
ln -s ~/[...]/gremlin ~/sc/gremlin
```

`~/sc/gremlin` is in `$PATH`.
Calling the script directly works.
Calling it through the link doesn't.
It uses `dirname $0` so it gets nothing.

Is there a way to make this setup work without changing the script and without creating another one in place of the soft link?

This is how $0 is used:

```
case `uname` in
  CYGWIN*)
    CP=$( echo `dirname $0`/../lib/*.jar . | sed 's/ /;/g')
    ;;
  *)
    CP=$( echo `dirname $0`/../lib/*.jar . | sed 's/ /:/g')
esac
```

Comment: `ln -s ~/.../gremlin ~/sc/gremlin` creates a bad link.  Try with just two dots: `rm ~/sc/gremlin; ln -s ~/../gremlin ~/sc/gremlin`.

Comment: No, ... means some path like ~/sw/prog/database/titan/gremlin/2.6.0/bin/gremlin . I just didn't want it to be long. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether the use of `dirname $0` is a problem or not would depend on *how* it is used.  Without more details, we cannot answer that.

If (a) the use of `dirname $0` is a problem and (b) you cannot change the script, then the solution is to replace the soft link `~/sc/gremlin` with a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec ~/../gremlin "$@"
```

In this way, `~/../gremlin` will run with a correct `$0`.

The use of `exec` means that the process running the script `~/../gremlin` will replace the process running `~/sc/gremlin`.  This is more efficient that keeping both processes around until `~/../gremlin` completed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to derive the `~/...` directory from `$0`, as opposed to `~/sc` from within the script, you could do:

If it's a `zsh` script:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
dir=$0:A:h
```

Otherwise, and provided you have a `readlink` command that behaves like GNU's one (some systems have a `realpath` command which you may be able to use instead):

```
#! /bin/sh -
dir=$(dirname -- "$(readlink -f -- "$0")")
```

`readlink -f` and `$0:A` give you the *canonical* path of the file, that is an absolute path after resolution of all symlinks in all path components.

And then:

```
set -- "$dir"/../lib/*.jar .
case $(uname) in
  CYGWIN*) IFS=';';;
  *)       IFS=:;;
esac
CP="$*"
```

Or:

```
case $(uname) in
  CYGWIN*) sep=';';;
  *)       sep=:;;
esac
CP=$(printf "%s$sep" "$dir"/../lib/*.jar).
```

Comment: This sounds good, I'm going to try if the resolving counts with $PATH.

Answer (score 0):

As @john1024 pointed out, the typo in OP's question may be the point of the question:

```
ln -s ~/.../gremlin ~/sc/gremlin
```

While a few applications honor triple-dots, the Unix filesystems do not.  Your **shell** expands the `~` (tilde), not `ln`, so

```
    ln -s ~/../gremlin ~/sc/gremlin
```

would expand the pathname as expected.  If the link already exists, you can overwrite it using the `-f` option.  However, if the target is an actual file, the `-f` option will silently overwrite the file with a symbolic link.  You might want to use the `-i` option which at least tells you there is something already there.

If you want to validate the link (prove that it points to a file), the `-L` option of `ls` is useful:

```
ls -lL ~/sc/gremlin
```

If it is not a file, `ls` will (depending on implementation) show just a `l` for the type (the first character of the listing), with question marks for the permission bits), or some other indication that it is not pointing to a real file (OSX simply refuses to show anything at all in this case, although it counts the size of the symbolic link in the total).

Further reading:

- [Triple dot wildcards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182548/triple-dot-wildcards)
- [What happened to the ability to use … (three dots) to refer to the grandparent directory?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160202-00/?p=92953)
- [4.5.1 Ellipsis Wildcard Character](http://h41379.www4.hpe.com/doc/731final/6489/6489pro_009.html) (a feature of VMS from the 1980s)